# System.IO.Exception when converting DOC to RTF

Tags: c#

I have code like this:

```
DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application newApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            object Source = file;
            object Target = Path.ChangeExtension(file, ".rtf");
            object Unknown = Type.Missing;
            newApp.Documents.Open(ref Source, ref Unknown,
                 ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown,
                 ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown,
                 ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown,
                 ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown);
            object format = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatRTF;
            newApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs(ref Target, ref format,
                    ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown,
                    ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown,
                    ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown,
                    ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown,
                    ref Unknown, ref Unknown);
 newApp.Quit(ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown);
richTextBox1.LoadFile(Path.ChangeExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName, ".rtf")); }
```

And when I debugged my program, it gave a System.IO.IOException error (The file is being used at the final line of code).

Comment: It seems that the File system still has the file locked. I'd try to code a "wait a little and try again". Like wait for e.g. 100 ms and try again for example for 3 times. If it still throws the exception after 3 times of waiting and retry then give up and try to firgure out if the file is in fact still in use.

Comment: @Fildor I don't know what you mean, can you explain it?

Comment: See my answer as to what I mean exactly. For future questions: If you have an exception, add its stacktrace to the question.

Comment: BTW: you are using `object Source = file` but later you try to open `openFileDialog1.Filename` ... where does `file` come from?

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it works:

```
var rtfFileName = Path.ChangeExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName, ".rtf");
richTextBox1.LoadFile(rtfFileName);
```

Also make sure the file you are converting is not used by any other process.

Comment: on which line is it failing now?

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate what I wrote in the comment:

Instead of just doing this:

```
newApp.Quit(ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown);
richTextBox1.LoadFile(Path.ChangeExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName, ".rtf")); }
```

Try this:

```
newApp.Quit(ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown);

// Maybe try and add a little sleep here anyway, so the filesystem 
// gets a little time to update the file status.
//Thread.Sleep(100); 

for( int i = 3 ; i > 0 ; --i )
{
    try
    {
        richTextBox1.LoadFile(Path.ChangeExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName, ".rtf")); 
        break; // break out of for-loop if above line does not cause an exception
    }
    catch( IOException  )
    {
       if( i > 0 )
       {  // Retries left : wait a little and try again.
            Thread.Sleep(100);
       }
       else
       {  // No retries left : throw exception
           throw;
       }
    }
}
```